# htaccess generic Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following rewrite set up:

```
RewriteRule r/(.*) scripts/report.php?cp=1&id=$1
```

It works great to redirect mydomain.com/r/123abc but it's redirecting all pages on the server that begin with an "r". Does anyone know how I can make this more specific to only redirect when the url is mydomain.com/r/ ? 
I should note that I need to keep this generic so I can't include mydomain.com in the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a `^/` in front of your `r/(.*)` rewrite rule.  This would make it:

```
RewriteRule ^/r/(.*) scripts/report.php?cp=1&id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works for you (not tested), but try it out:

```
# Rewrite ini
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mydomain.com/

# Redirect all /mydomain.com/r/* calls to scripts/report.php
RewriteRule ^r/(.*)$ scripts/report.php?cp=1&id=$1 [QSA]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that the RegEx should match *the entire string* rather than just match the string. You can do this using the `^` and `$` symbols:

```
RewriteRule ^r/(.*)$ scripts/report.php?cp=1&id=$1
```